# How to scp all files (or select files) in a bash script

Tags: bash, scp

I am trying to write a bash script where I can upload all files (or ones that I name) in a current directory to a server using `scp`. The following command works in a bash script.

```
scp * username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2
```

However, I am trying to allow my script to either name a file (and eventually several files) or upload all files, a server, and a directory in my server. Why doesn't the following script work when inputting `*` as the first argument?

```
scp $1 $2:$3
```

When trying to upload a C++ project by using `*` in the current directory, it tells me:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname main.cpp: Name or service not known

If I just specify the file main.cpp it works fine, but for situations like this I don't want to have to specify the name of each file, as this could take a while for bigger projects.

Also, a side note, how could I allow a script like this to be able to specify a variable number of files and still have it be able to recognize my server name (for example, uploading 2 files or 5 that I specify as opposed to using *)?

Comment: How are you executing the script? Which arguments are you passing to it?

Comment: *, server, directory_in_server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell expands the wildcard when you use `*` as the parameter of the script. So if you do:

```
scriptname * user@host directory
```

it becomes

```
scriptname file1 file2 file3 file4 user@host directory
```

So then the script tries to do:

```
scp file1 file2:file3
```

If you want the wildcard to be sent literally to the script you need to quote it:

```
scriptname "*" user@host directory
```

The wildcard will be expanded when the script uses the variable `$1`, since you haven't quoted it. You should quote all the other variables, since you don't want them to undergo further expansion:

```
scp $1 "$2:$3"
```

Another option is to change your script so you put the fixed arguments first:

```
scriptname user@host directory filenames
```

Then the script can remove those fixed arguments, and use `"$@"` to get the rest:

```
dest=$1
dir=$2
shift 2
scp "$@" "$dest:$dir"
```

Comment: So the purpose of `shift 2` in your final is to make `"$@"` apply to everything but the first two?

Comment: Yes. It removes the first 2 arguments from the positional parameters.